# Getting rid of kelvin_cell mesh n Blender

Tags: modeling

Is it possible to reduce the meshing of the kelvin cell shown in the picture in blender to the point where i nearly have a clear cylinder?

[image]

I tried with Decimate from tools and that is the best that I have done:
From this:

[image]

I went to this:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it automatically, but this mesh can be mirrored 4 times, so that it lower the amount of work to do it manually.